Selenium Drop Down
I am trying to learn Selenium. For my small project, I am trying to automate amazon shopping cart.  My flow is simple:

Open amazon.com
Search a product
Select size
Add to cart.

I am getting an error on Select Size.
@Test(priority = 3, groups = {"Startshopping"})
    public <T> void addItemToCart() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("::::addItemToCart");

        // Navigate to the product page
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Speedo-Rubber-Swim-X-Small-Yellow/dp/B005FYF9MU/ref=sr_1_5?crid=3720YVMBX45Q6&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.y9eXnqIydahqg0WjO3ehKHM65sn9kbsKPyhIxHga-HIlCuf7zQlZnqY6FxkBOW7DL-5MpTHyDd2qZEbexu2biaX6rOlb_zQC_HxBog7hE2w2B56sqg9S6lNjLhjvhiqoT-5hhn0sxvw6o7wFIW0gtEOd1tLKD7LyYtOjyiLY0CsKpF6mP0Xzwng1s1tF5N32s2XNby9LFVRfDXwCdcv8o-8YghwuEPzTiUzxfMZ8Nrr5vMxNBKGHR2pjgVJL1mJSrPz7WKaVkrRDFrzNGbKlUA7xM-fB1IDnRFHcGIuTzFU.nxFQ-aNfenY6irxxGenpBoDDaUxwWQLI3DDwCnItVrk&dib_tag=se&keywords=swimming%2Bfins%2Bxs&qid=1724391120&sprefix=%2Caps%2C73&sr=8-5&th=1");

        //dp = driver.findElement(By.id("wpj3eu-brkvgc-dqr1de-o8f8rv"));
        
        WebElement dp = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("dropdown_selected_size_name")));
      
            // Perform actions on the element
        dp.click();
        
        Select select= new Select(dp);
        //select.selectByIndex(3);
        //driver.findElement(By.id("add-to-cart-button")).click();
    }

PASSED: com.seleniumframework.Amazonshopping.navigateToAmazon
PASSED: com.seleniumframework.Amazonshopping.searchItem
FAILED: com.seleniumframework.Amazonshopping.addItemToCart
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "SPAN"
Build info: version: '4.22.0', revision: 'c5f3146703*'

Any pointers?
I expect my code should select the drop down and select one of the options.

when you type to Select, it's throwing because your element is not a  tag.  It's a .  See if you can find/target the  tag if you want to use the special Select type.  (some JS type pulldowns may use different structures... you might find that the  is overlaying the  or that the  has no  tags which might be needed when using new Select() type)

You can use @FindBy annotation to find a Web element, then you need to declare your Select and give it a Web element.
@FindBy(id = "dropdown_selected_size_name")
private Webelement dp;

Select select = new Select(dp);
select.selectByIndex(1).click();

